# Getting Count from Large IEnumerable

Tags: mysql, performance, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I have a dataset of 3 inner joined tables consisting of around 18,000 records from a  MySQL database. My function is supposed to be getting all of the relevant data, then filtering it by some parameters supplied by a user, then returning the count of items for which the filter applies.

This did work fine when I was using a standard data reader, however I have just moved the application over to use entity framework to try and improve on performance, for this I am using LazyLoadingProxies - which I believe is relevant to the issue.

The main parts of my function are

1. get all data items
2. (for each parameter) make a clone of alldata items
3. Get the count of filtered items

The code looks like this

```
var EventsLogged = context.EventLogs.Where(x => x.Event.GameId == request.GameId
                                     && (!request.EventId.HasValue || x.EventId == request.EventId.Value)
                                     && (!request.StartTime.HasValue || x.Created >= request.StartTime.Value)
                                     && (!request.EndTime.HasValue || x.Created <= request.EndTime.Value));




if (EventsLogged.Count() <= 0)
{
    response.AddErorrMessage("No data found for Event.");
}
else
{
    //Some other stuff happens here not related to do with working on the parameters

    IEnumerable<EventLogs> filteredEvents = EventsLogged;
    filteredEvents = FilterResultsSet(filteredEvents, parametervalue);

    return filteredEvents.Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count();
}
```

The function works fine, filtering is fine and then when we hit the Select.Distinct().Count() the processing time shoots up to an insane amount - I waited around 20 minutes before giving up.

In my output window I can see sections of SQL being output as if the query is actually being executed at this point, but only 1 record at a time.

From what I've looked at already there are some rules around getting the count of an IEnumerable and that to get the count it has to be numerated.

As I don't care for any of the content in this query, just the count, is there any way I can achieve this - or do I need to rethink my whole strategy.

Comment: What does `FilterResultsSet()` look like? Is it returning an `IQueryable<>`? If so, and if it seems fast, it could be that, until you actually do that `.Select()`, you are not materializing the records, and whatever you do in `FilterResultsSet()` might be inefficient

Comment: `NULLable` columns _and testing for such_ is poorly optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following advice from both comments I tried to remove the NULLABLE items from my search. However this didn't optimise much more.

As suspected it was the LazyLoadingProxies causing issues - when running the .SELECT() Entity Framework was going off and trying to populate my dataset, however it had no context of what I actually wanted, so it was trying to resolve, and get a large set of data; which also had a relationship loop in it i.e 4 tables were linked together via foreign keys - so I imagine it was trying to resolve that all at once.

When I removed the lazy loading I had to specify which navigation properties I wanted to resolve using .Include() and .ThenInclude() options.

The working code was as follows

```
List<EventsLogged> EventsLogged = context.EventLogs
                                            .Include(log => log.Session)
                                            .Include(log => log.EventParameterValues)
                                                .ThenInclude(val => val.EventParameter)
                                            .Where(x => x.Event.GameId == request.GameId).ToList();
```